# Visual Studio 2017 PCH doesn't improve build time

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2017, building, pch

I enabled PCH for one project. Added all commonly used headers(from C++ std lib and boost) into `stdafx.h`, added `stdafx.cpp` and included `stdafx.h` there. I selected `Create` in the properties of `stdafx.cpp` and selected `Use` in the project settings. Also I added `stdafx.h` in the `/FI` option - to avoid including `stdafx.h` in every unit.

When I rebuild the whole project, it firstly complies `stdafx.cpp` and the quickly the other `*.cpp` files - it's OK, and it seems to be working. But if I change a file and then build the project, it takes lots lots of time to recompile that single file, comparably with rebuilding the whole project, so it seems that PCH doesn't work, or it rebuilds PCH file, or what?

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in /FI option, when I explicitly included `stdafx.h` in every cpp file, the problem disappeared.